# How to translate Wordpress content of post or page with .po files

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, wpml, qtranslate

For Wordpress/WooCommerce, I want to find a plugin to translate content of post, pages, custom post-types, like based on .po files, not WPML because a lot of paragraph need to reuse that.

What can I use for this purpose?

Comment: To reopen your question, you could edit it changing a bit the title with something like: « How to translate Wordpress content of post or page with .po files ». And the content with something like: « I would like to find a way to translate content of post or pages with something based on `.po` files, not WPML plugin because a lot of paragraph to reuse. How can I do this? ». I think it could help some people… then you could flag it asking for reopening…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't translate content of posts or pages with something based on `.po` / `.mo` files, because it is only for theme or plugin localisation, but not for multi language content.

For content translation in Wordpress, you can chose between two:

- **Qtranslate** *free* plugin
- **WPML** *commercial* plugin

Each one has its strengths and weaknesses…

---

Comparison: [Comparing WPML to Free and Paid Alternatives](https://wpml.org/home/comparing-wpml-free-paid-alternatives/)