# Best way to build a Wordpress Bi-lingual Site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translate

I would like to have an English version of my Wordpress site (which is already up and running) and also a French version of the same site. However, I do not want to automatically translate everything with a generator but translate it myself into French. The problem is there is also a Woocommerce store on the site and that, along with all of it's elements, emails sent to customers, etc, will also have to be translated.

Does anyone have thoughts on the best way to approach doing this? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read into creating a Multisite - http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: There is 2 consistent options for a [multilingual e-commerce website based on WooCommerce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831236/wordpress-plugin-to-translate-content-of-post-or-page/36831431#36831431). The Best and most complete one is [tag:WPML] commercial plugin. The other choice is a free plugin, but much more difficult and incomplete, depending on your shop settings and choices.

Answer (score 0):

The must-have free plugin which will help you do the job is [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). Coupled with [Polylang theme strings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang-theme-strings/), you will be allowed to automatically detect strings in your wordpress installation you wish to translate. Polylang has great support that will help you easily configure language switcher on your website. You could also take a look at [LoCo Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/), a very nice plugin which allows you to translate your wordpress installation.