# WooCommerce Shop: Geo Redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation

I'm creating a Woo Commerce based E-commerce website, Now I want to redirect visitors while visiting Woo Commerce Shop country wise.

Ex. If a visitor accesses Shop from U.S. (example.com/shop) it redirects the visitor to my specific page (example.com/shop/us or example.com/us-shop). Is it possible?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: On a multilingual shop yes this can be done… But you will need [**to add a multilingual plugin**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831431/3730754).